# Modify the Event Log Source name for an SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging, ssis, event-log

I have an SQL Server integration Services (SSIS) package using the standard *Event Log*  provider (yes, the event log! I know we can use SQL etc...)

The default "Source" of the log events is **"SQLISPackage100**" but I want it to be something like **"AppName"** so that the errors are more visible between the different packages when viewing the event log (also for MOM use).

```
Event Type:      Error
Event Source:    SQLISPackage100
Event Category:  None
...
Description:
  Package "Foo" failed.
```

I hope the answer is simple, I simply cannot find it, but does anyone know how to ***change the text of the Event Log Source*** name to something more meaningful?

PK  :-)

Comment: Same problem: have you found a solution?

Comment: No - we just put up with the non-descript name. The problem is disappearing as we are moving away from the SSIS solution soon anyway... :o|

Comment: 7 years later and this is the only place I can even find someone asking how to do this - sigh!

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the name of the package in the package properties?

Comment: Yes - e.g. "Foo_Import_Package". I have searched the XML files for the string "SQLISPackage100" but can't find any (I can only assume its some sort of default value)